# Why are children described as "folly free" in the poem "Mothers Heart"?

Tags: poetry, uyghur-language, drops-of-melodies, hemirah-tohti

The poem *Mothers Heart* (in *Drops of Melodies* by  Hemirah Tohti) contains the following lines:

> She always thinks of her children
> Children play, folly free

Why are children described as "folly free"?

Image of the entire poem for those that don't own the book:
[image]

Transcription:

> Mother cries for children worries
> Child innocent clueless
> Once understand mothers heart
> They won't be able to find
> No matter here search
> Mothers heart endless ocean
> Can fit into boundless need
> That fire burns eternally
> In mothers heart
> But she does not complain
> Warm food comes in front of her
> She always thinks of her children
> Children play, folly free
> Wouldn't think of mother just once
> Mother chases worries of children
> Washes her face with tears
> The child cannot understand
> Mothers world
> Even in their suffering
> Mother only thinks of household life
> Bitterness swallowed
> Preying [sic] for a long life
> When children are grown

Original Arabic from the book (sorry for the poor image, I'm editing from my phone):

[image]

Comment: Considering that this poem doesn't seem to be available online, could you please link to a screenshot or photo of the whole poem, or just include the full text here, if it's not too long? (Context may be important.)

Comment: @CDR I added an image as well as its transcription (due to the [reasons listed here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/4032703)).

Comment: Thanks! Though if you posted the lines themselves, I don't think the image is necessary...up to you.

Comment: Considering the obvious misprint "Preying" for "praying," I wonder whether "folly" is a similar misprint for "fully." The alternative is that worrying is folly, which wouldn't make all that much sense. Or it's an inaccurate translation and the word is supposed to be "foolish," adjective rather than noun.

Comment: While the author could be writing poetically, this could also just be a translation error (I believe the book was not professionally translated). If the book includes the original Arabic text, could you include it, so someone fluent in Uyghur Arabic (not me!) could check?

Comment: @ClaraDiazSanchez I added a screenshot, I'll try to replace it with a better one once I'm near a computer.

Comment: I don't think "folly free" here means devoid of folly, the way "sugar free" on a beverage label means devoid of sugar. I suspect it means instead that children at play enjoy the freedom to be goofy.

Comment: Translating poetry is perilous and nitpicking them has to involve someone who speaks the language if you really want to do that. That entire Mothers thing is a mess, at the beginning.